# ¿Cómo cambiar el título de la terminal de Linux en Node.js?

Tags: nodejs, terminal

Quiero cambiar el título de la terminal en *Linux* desde *Node.js*. ¿Es posible esto?

Estoy en *ArchLinux*, en la distribución *Manjaro*, la terminal es de *Xfce*.

[image: terminal]

Como se puede ver, en este momento el título es `arteze@arteze`, quisiera cambiarlo desde *Node.js*, algo como esto. ¿Es posible? ¿Cómo se puede hacer?

```
cambiar_título("Título nuevo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En *bash* el título se puede cambiar con el siguiente comando `printf`.

```
printf '\e]2;Título\a'
```

Documentación de *xterm* donde explica qué es cada caracter: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html

- `\e` es el caracter de `Escape`. En octal es `\033`, y en hexadecimal es `\x1B`
- `\a` es el caracter `Bell` (campana). En octal es `\007`, y en hexadecimal es `\x07`
- `]2` es para cambiar solo el título, si fuera `\]0` se podría cambiar el ícono y el título, y si fuera `]1` se cambia solo el ícono.

Un equivalente en *Node.js* es `process.stdout.write`.

```
var título = "Título"
process.stdout.write(`\x1B]2;${título}\x07`)
```

En el siguiente ejemplo se cambia el título cada un segundo y no es necesario requerir módulos.

```
function cambiar_título(título){
    process.stdout.write(`\x1B]2;${título}\x07`)
}

setInterval(function(){
    try{i}catch(e){i=0}
    cambiar_título("Título " + i++)
},1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede cambiar el título en *bash*, tiene algunos caracteres bastante extraños, por ejemplo, `\a` significa alarma o timbre.

```
echo $'\033]0;Titulo\a'
```

Esto funciona desde *bash*, pero para eso es necesario asignarlo a `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo $'\033]0;TÍtulo\a'"
```

En *Node.js* no hay que usar `PROMPT_COMMAND`, solo el `echo`. Se puede hacer de dos maneras, una es con el módulo `shelljs`, y la otra es con `child_process`:

Luego para convertir el comando de bash a un *string* de *JavaScript*, es necesario escapar algunos caracteres:

```
echo $'\\033]0;Título\\a'
```

En este caso, solo hay que escapar la barra invertida.

### Solución mediante `child_process`

Declaro el `exec` al requerir el módulo `child_process`. Aquí, se cambia **de manera asíncrona**.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec
```

Declaro el título en una variable, puedo usar un string normal, que se encierra entre comillas dobles, o plantillas, que se encierra entre comillas invertidas. En este caso prefiero la segunda forma.

Luego llamo a la función `exec`, escapando la barra invertida en ambos lugares, `\\033` y `\\a`, y el título lo encierro entre el signo pesos con corchetes `${título}`.

```
var título = "título"
exec(`echo -n $'\\033]0;${título}\\a'`)
```

Por último hago una unión entre la ejecución del comando y la salida del programa, con el método `stdout`, de esta manera `exec(comando).stdout.pipe(process.stdout)`.

El siguiente código de ejemplo, cambia el título cada un segundo con un contador:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec

function cambiar_título(título){
    exec(`echo -n $'\\033]0;${título}\\a'`).stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
}

var i = 0
setInterval(function(){
    cambiar_título("Título " + i++)
},1000)
```

El comando ejecutado va cambiando. Además, al `echo` le agrego el parámetro `-n` para que no muestre el salto de línea.

### Solución mediante `shelljs`

Se declara el `exec`, de forma predeterminada, `shelljs` ejecuta el comando **de manera síncrona**:

```
var exec = require('shelljs').exec
```

De la misma manera que en el ejemplo anterior, se puede declarar un string normal o un template, es decir, la plantilla, en este caso prefiero usar el normal, y concateno el título con un `+`.

```
"echo -n $'\\033]0;" + título + "\\a'"
```

Al ser una función síncrona, el proceso tarda más.

Código:

```
var exec = require('shelljs').exec

function cambiar_título(título){
    exec("echo -n $'\\033]0;" + título + "\\a'")
}

var i = 0
setInterval(function(){
    cambiar_título("Título " + i++)
},1000)
```

Aquí no se hace la unión `pipe` con `stdout`, el módulo `shelljs` internamente tiene esas funciones.